# Swapping endianess using Qt and template

Tags: c++, qt, templates, endianness, template-specialization

I am using **Qt** to swap endianess while reading a buffer field by field and putting the result into a data structure.

Since the structure's field are both integral types and floating point types, I was trying to use **template** and **template specialization**, but my code does not compile.

The reason of template specialization is to avoid calling Qt facilities for the floating point types, since they are not defined for such types (because endianess is a integer-only issue). But compiler complains that I am still calling the `qFromBigEndian` function for the `float`.

Here is the code:

```
class Iterator
    {
    public:

        inline Iterator(const char * buffer)   :
            _it(buffer)
        {}

        template <typename T>
        inline void readNext(T & field)
        {
            field = qFromBigEndian(*reinterpret_cast<const T *>(_it));
            _it += sizeof(T);
        }

        template <>
        inline void readNext<float>(float & field)
        {
            field = *reinterpret_cast<const float *>(_it);
            _it += sizeof(float);
        }

        template <>
        inline void readNext<double>(double & field)
        {
            field = *reinterpret_cast<const double *>(_it);
            _it += sizeof(double);
        }

    private:

        const char * _it;
    };
```

Comment: looks like you are trying do something what is already done. Simply use [QDataStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdatastream.html).

Comment: Nice tip. I'm trying to use QDataStream but unfortunately it is not working: in breaks upon the floating point fields. I should post another question to explain that...

Comment: read documentation more carefully. Check: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdatastream.html#setFloatingPointPrecision

Comment: I've read about that method, but I just do not want to switch floating point precision since some fields are double, others are floats, and that can change. I would like for it to be templated in the operator>>, but it looks like it is not.

Comment: read again! Set version `Qt_4_5` and it will work as you need once as 32 bit for `float` and 64 bits for `double`.

Comment: That worked! One of the rare case in which a previous Qt version in indeed WAY better than the new one! Thanks a lot

Comment: To be clear: It is not Qt version, but `QDataStream` binary format version, which is in correlation to Qt version!